# Play audio on keydown

Tags: javascript, audio, key

I have the code to launch an event when pressing a key.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       alert( "left pressed" );
       return false;
    }
});
```

I was wondering how can I launch a sound

in my html I have this :

```
<audio id="sound1" src="images/step-1/iphone.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="sound2" src="images/step-1/iphone.mp3"></audio>

<div id="pad">

    <img src="images/step-1/tsonga.jpg" onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play()"/>
    <img src="images/step-1/federer.jpg" onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play()"/>

</div>
```

Like this, but it doesn't work :/

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       getElementById('sound1').play()
       return false;
    }
});
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: did the Developer Console in browser show any error ? Also, which browser (and version) are you using? does it support Audio tag ?

Comment: What browser are you using ? (Firefox doesnt support .mp3 files on audio tag) http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp

Comment: document.getELementById

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       document.getElementById('sound1').play();
       return false;
    }
});
```

I think you have to use `document.getElementById` because if you just write getElementById the scope is window.

Comment: Please replace getElementById with document.getElementById and try it again.

Comment: Little other question, if I want to play play the sound several times without waiting the end of the it. Do I have to use something like .stop() ?

Comment: You have to set the playtime back to 0 by doing this:
document.getElementById('sound1').currentTime = 0;

Answer (score 1):

From W3Schools:

```
    <audio id="sound" controls>
      <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
      Your browser does not support this audio format.
    </audio>
```

Then:

```
document.getElementById('sound').play();
```